# Magento API Support

Tags: api, magento

I wonder if Magento provide API for following.

> 1. Product Search.
> 2. Add to Wishlist.
> 3. View wishlist.
> 4. Add to cart.

If it does provides API for above, Can any one share useful resource for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product Search - NO.
Add to Wishlist - NO.
View wishlist - NO.
Add to cart - YES. see `shoppingCartProductAdd` for V2 and `shopping_cart_product.add` for V1

Comment: Are this Restfull API's ?

Comment: @Rakesh Nope. SOAP API. The REST API does not support any of the things on your list.

Comment: Thanks Marius for your help. I wonder if we can develop custom API for such thing. is it possible?

Comment: That too using Rest. I am in need of this, since i have to implement such API, so that i can use it in my mobile application.

Answer (score 2):

Product Search.
Add to Wishlist.
View wishlist.
Add to cart.

- Product Search -> *YES*. Provided By magento2.
- Add to Wishlist ->Not sure.
- View wishlist -> Not sure
- Add to cart ->  *YES*. Provided By magento2.

### Product search Api in Magento 2:

http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=name&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=%25<**Name_Of_Product**>%25&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][condition_type]=like

### Add To Cart Api In Magento 2:

http://localhost/magento/rest/V1/carts/mine/items/

**Note** : Add Items to a cart of a registered customer.
Two things we have to send in request, first token &
 second is cartItems detail.
e.g.
*Body to be load in POST request*

> {"cartItem": {"**sku**": "WS1M-Orange-Flav","**qty**":
>   1,"**quote_id**": "4"}}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Magento API is extendable using custom API models in your extension. We are frequently using Magento API extends for both inbound/outbound calls. Magento supports multiple API backends - Rest, SOAP, XML-RPC (v1), v2 only REST and SOAP if I remember correctly.

Magento 1

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/Resources/resources.html

Magento 2
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html