# add product to wishlist in magento API

Tags: magento

I have checked in magento soap API but I can not find API for add product to wish list so I am developing own API but I don't know what is the problem with my code so please help me to find solution.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    
    require_once '../app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    
      
      
      $customer_id = $_GET['customer_id'];
      $product_id  = $_GET['product_id'];
    
      $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
      $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
      $product  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    
      $customer->load($customer_id); 
      $wishlist->loadByCustomer($customer_id);
    
      $res = $wishlist->addNewItem($product->load($product_id));
      if($res)
      {
        $status =1;
        $message = "your product has been added in wishlist";
      }
      
      else
      {
        $status =0;
        $message = "wrong data send";
      }
    
      $result = array("status" =>$status,"message"=>$message);
      header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
      echo json_encode($result);
    ?>
```

Comment: can you try this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19678/how-do-i-add-to-wishlist-programatically

Comment: I have tried this too but also not working if you can see my code suggest me then it will be good.

in that link there is "$buyRequest = new Varien_Object(array());"

Comment: @kailash yadav $buyRequest = new Varien_Object(array());"
above code is for what??
I am not understaing
if you can code here for me then it will be great

Answer (score 0):

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20261831/magento-api-support/37970584#37970584) you might want to check.

In your code you are not extending Magento API in any way but creating a standalone hackish script that inserts items to wishlist. I suggest that you take a look on how to develop a magento extension or if you need to create a backend (CLI) script, at least use the same structure as in shell/abstract.php and extend the shell base class - you will save yourself loads of headaches.

Moreover, your code is not secure, maintainable and removes all the benefits of using Magento as an ecommerce platform/framework (security, authorization & authentication etc)

Inchoo have quite some blog posts that could give you an idea where to begin

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-api-v2/

http://inchoo.net/magento/extending-the-magento-api/

Answer (score -1):

/* error_reporting(E_ALL); 
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);*/
You Have Comment This line And Write this

require_once './app/Mage.php';